# How to version control code on my godaddy shared plan

Tags: version-control, version

Godaddy hosts my website on a shared plan.  I'm starting to work with another developer now and version control would be helpful.

Does anyone know if I can:
(1) Install some sort of version control directly on GoDaddy?
or 
(2) Use a 3rd party version control that both developers can access remotely, which has ftp, which could be used to upload files to GoDaddy?

I know 2 seems kind of silly.  If files are already getting uploaded somewhere with version control I might as well host the files there.  I suggested option 2 because I'm nervous to change hosts (I've not used another host before).

If anyone has been in my situation I would appreciate hearing what they did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/), if its ok for your code to be public, otherwise you can find more solutions in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233219/assembla-is-no-longer-free-is-there-a-good-alternative).